# No internet in Android Virtual device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

In Settings on the virtual device it has full signal strength to `AndroidWifi` and a line below that says

```
Connected, no internet
```

Shouldn't this just work? I'm not behind a proxy, firewall or anything. On my laptop the internet just works without any special configuration.

- Android Studio 3.3.1
- Android Emulator 28.0.23
- MacOS 10.14.2

What must I do to connect the virtual device to the internet?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have DNS address problem. Try these steps on MacOs:

- Open "System Preferences"
- Click on "Network"
- Select the network which your computer is connected and click on "Advanced"
- Select "DNS", Select the "+" button, type "8.8.8.8"
- Select "Ok" and "Apply"

After that close the emulator and start it again.

Comment: That did work! I don't understand why though. Why is the DNS from the internet provider not good enough for AVD?

Comment: How does this solve the issue